# How to add Tags to my aws resources globally

Tags: yaml

How to add tags for all resources in my stack in cloudformation template(yaml), I need sample cloudformation template to add tags globally in one stack please help me with the template

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Resource Tags property to apply tags to resources, which can help you identify and categorize those resources. You can tag only resources for which AWS CloudFormation supports tagging.
Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html

OR
Another option would be during the time when you create/update a cloud formation template, in configure stack options you can mention the tags i.e. key, value which will be applied to the resources in your stack.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Am I able to add globally for all resources in single tag if it so can you please tell me how I need to add it

Comment: Ok, so if I understood this correctly. You want a centralized cloudformation templates which will contain only tags and other templates will refer these tags from the centralized template? If so then I don't think using cloudformation it will be possible. Though using terraform you should be able to achieve this. Hope this is clear

Comment: Hi, if this solves your problem then kindly accept the answer